# Why does function only return var if I make it global?

Tags: python, function, variables

Why does the first function 'define_vartest' not return the var as expected. Not until I make it global (the second function 'define_vartest_global'), does it work. And what is the difference between returning a var at the end of a function and defining a global var within same function??? I am puzzled.

```
def define_vartest():

    vartest = 1

    return vartest


def define_vartest_global():

    global vartest_global
    vartest_global = 1

    return vartest_global

define_vartest()

define_vartest_global()

#print('vartest', vartest)
print('vartest_global', vartest_global)
```

Basically - if I remove the rem from the print vartest line the script stops. Why does the var not get defined, as I return it from the function?

Please explain

---

Answered below.

This code works as expected. Thanks

```
    def define_vartest():

        vartest = 1

        return vartest


    def define_vartest_global():

        global vartest_global
        vartest_global = 1

        return vartest_global

    vartest = define_vartest()

    vartest_global = define_vartest_global()


    print('vartest', vartest) 
    print('vartest_global', vartest_global)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must assign the value you return:

```
def define_vartest():
    vartest = 1
    return vartest

vartest = define_vartest()
print('vartest', vartest)
```

Otherwise the print statement will be unable to see it, because they are in different scope.

This mean that `vartest` inside the function and `vartest` outside are different variables. With the `return` you give the value of the `vartest` inside to the `vartest` outside.

Comment: Wauw. I think I must have missed this assignment in all the material I have read during my first year as a programmer.

The var is spelled wrong - but great and short answer - Thanks k4ppa

Answer (score 1):

Because you never read the returned value. Think about this:

```
def foo():
    return 1

foo()
```

What is going to happen with the `1`? It's lost since no one cares. You need to save it in a new variable to keep it:

```
def foo():
    return 1

vartest = foo()
```

Now let's add a local variable:

```
def foo():
    a = 1
    return a

b = foo() # assign the result of the function call to "b"
# "a" is undefined since it's local to "foo"
print('b',b)
```

This effect is called "scoping". Each variable has a "scope", a kind of horizon within which it is visible. It's not visible outside. That way, you can reuse names in different functions.

Comment: Hmm - I have many functions that return many vars. How do I assign those to their respective var outside the function. That seems like a mess.

Comment: You need to do that on an individual basis. If it didn't work that way, all functions could see all variables. If that happened, adding another function would mean that you have to check all existing functions to make sure you don't accidentally use or change their variables.